# Javascript - Homing bullet

Tags: javascript

I've been working on a little project, and while I can get the bullet to home in on the mouse, it has some strange behavior.

If the bullet is going perfectly left/right/up/down from the mouse, it will constantly change direction back and forth and just continue to fly away from the mouse instead of turning back at it. Also, sometimes it just makes loops that are unnecessary, but I figure that's because I'm not keeping the direction positive or negative (I could be wrong though).

http://codepen.io/EvanWard/pen/vOeGdO?editors=001

this is the code i have updating the singular bullet.

```
var target = App.mouse.subtract(App.bullet.pos),
      angle = target.angle();

  if(angle < 0) {
    angle += Math.PI * 2;
  }
  var delta = angle - App.bullet.dir;
  if(Math.abs(delta) > 180) {
    if(delta < 0) {
      delta += 180;
      delta *= -1;
    }
    else {
      delta -= 180;
      delta *= -1;
    }
  }
  if(App.bullet.dir > Math.PI * 2) {
    App.bullet.dir -= Math.PI * 2;
  }

  App.bullet.dir += delta/10;
  App.bullet.pos.x += Math.cos(App.bullet.dir) * App.bullet.vel;
  App.bullet.pos.y += Math.sin(App.bullet.dir) * App.bullet.vel;
```

Comment: When you say `Math.abs(delta) > 180` do you really mean 180 or `Math.PI`? Because 10313.2403 degrees is such an arbitrarily strange angle

Comment: Boy, how'd I miss that one. Thanks, it fixes a little bit, but doesn't still seems to have some issues, particularly when the bullet is to the left of the mouse. it seems to change direction too abruptly.